# django view i get this error Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-views

went i run this code y get this error in the browser

error browser chrome
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

my view

```
    {% block beneficios %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
     var $this = $(this),
         loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
         targ = $this.attr('data-target');

     $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
     });

     $this.tab('show');
     return false;
     });

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]:first').click();
     });
     </script>

     <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
     <li><a href="{% url 'detalle3' pk=1 %}" data-target="#contacts"    class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'detalle3' pk=2 %}" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
   <li><a href="{% url 'detalle3' pk=3 %}" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
   </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="awaiting_request">
    </div>
    </div>  
   {% endblock beneficios %}
```

it supose to show de content of the link in the tab, but all it does y redirect me to the link

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. 
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/beneficiarios/afiliacion/1/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: my question is what's wrong with this code it doesn't work, it supose to load the link in the tab

Comment: This happens because your ajax request is synchronous for some reason. Did you do $.ajaxSetup({async: false});  anywhere before in your code?

Comment: i did it, now don't show the error only navigate to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/beneficiarios/afiliacion/1/  doesn't show the content in the tab